# Why does my lua5.1 bytecode compiler generate bad bytecode?

Tags: lua

I have a table of lua5.1 vm instructions that looks like this:
{
{op=5, A=0, Bx=1, const="Print}
More instructions
}
And I am trying to turn these instructions into bytecode that can be sucessfully ran through a LBI(Lua Bytecode Interpreter).
My code geneerates some bytecode but it is really bad and cannot be ran through a LBI
What is wrong with it?

```
local function tenseRecompiler(instructions, constants)
  local header = string.char(0x1B, 0x4C, 0x75, 0x61, 0x51, 0x00, 0x01, 0x04, 0x04, 0x04, 0x08)
  local lua_opcode_types = {
    "ABC",  "ABx", "ABC",  "ABC",
    "ABC",  "ABx", "ABC",  "ABx",
    "ABC",  "ABC", "ABC",  "ABC",
    "ABC",  "ABC", "ABC",  "ABC",
    "ABC",  "ABC", "ABC",  "ABC",
    "ABC",  "ABC", "AsBx", "ABC",
    "ABC",  "ABC", "ABC",  "ABC",
    "ABC",  "ABC", "ABC",  "AsBx",
    "AsBx", "ABC", "ABC", "ABC",
    "ABx",  "ABC",
  }
  local function encodeByte(value)
    return string.char(value)
  end

  local function encodeInt16(value)
    return string.char(value % 256) .. string.char(math.floor(value / 256) % 256)
  end

  local function encodeInt32(value)
    return string.char(value % 256) .. string.char(math.floor(value / 256) % 256) ..
           string.char(math.floor(value / 65536) % 256) .. string.char(math.floor(value / 16777216) % 256)
  end

  local bytecodeLines = {}
  local lineInfo = {}
  for i, v in pairs(instructions) do
    local op = v.op or -1 -- -1 is not a valid OPCODE, so it is an error
    local a = v.A or 0
    local b = v.B or 0
    local c = v.C or 0
    local Bx = v.Bx or 0
    local sBx = v.sBx or 0
    if op == -1 then
      print("Invalid OPCODE")
      do return end
    end
    if lua_opcode_types[op] == "ABC" then --ABC
      bytecodeLines[#bytecodeLines + 1] = encodeByte(a)
      bytecodeLines[#bytecodeLines + 1] = encodeByte(b)
      bytecodeLines[#bytecodeLines + 1] = encodeByte(c)
    elseif lua_opcode_types[op] == "AsBx" then --AsBx
      bytecodeLines[#bytecodeLines + 1] = encodeByte(a)
      bytecodeLines[#bytecodeLines + 1] = encodeInt32(sBx)
    elseif lua_opcode_types[op] == "ABx" then --ABx
      bytecodeLines[#bytecodeLines + 1] = encodeByte(a)
      bytecodeLines[#bytecodeLines + 1] = encodeInt16(Bx)
    end
    lineInfo[#bytecodeLines + 1] = 1
  end
  local constMap = {}
  local constCount = 0
  for _, const in ipairs(constants) do
    constCount = constCount + 1
    constMap[const] = constCount
    bytecodeLines[#bytecodeLines + 1] = encodeByte(0x1B) -- OP_CONSTANT
    bytecodeLines[#bytecodeLines + 1] = encodeByte(constCount)
    bytecodeLines[#bytecodeLines + 1] = const
  end
  local bytecode = table.concat(bytecodeLines)
  local bytecodeSize = #bytecode
  local constantCount = #constants
  local instructionCount = #instructions

  local lineInfoSize = #lineInfo * 4 -- Each line number is encoded as a 4-byte integer
  local sourceFileName = "@TENSE.lua"
  local sourceFileNameLength = #sourceFileName
  local sourceFileNameSize = sourceFileNameLength + 1 -- Include null terminator

  local bytecodeHeader = header ..
                         string.char(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0) ..
                          sourceFileName .. "@" ..
                         string.char(0,0,0,0,0,0,0) ..
                         "�" ..
                         string.char(0, 0, 0, 0)

  local bytecodeFile = bytecodeHeader .. bytecode .. table.concat(lineInfo)


  io.open("luac1.out", "wb"):write(bytecodeFile)
end
```

Thanks

I tried making it generate sucessful Bytecode and it isn't

Comment: What is the input and output of tenseRecompiler?  What is the error message from lbi?

Comment: This is typically called an "assembler" rather than a "compiler".

Comment: The `"�"` in your code is very suspect. If you do `utf8.codes"�"("�")`, you'll find that this is the actual replacement character - Unicode codepoint U+FFFD (decimal 65533). The UTF-8 encoding of the Unicode replacement character is most likely not the byte sequence you want in the bytecode header.

Comment: `op` isn't getting into the output? Lua operands are not usually byte-aligned... missing integrality byte in header, no length for chunk name, random extra `"@"` after chunk name, strange number of bytes before chunk name, no null terminator for chunk name, (as noted unicode replacement character), function header will at least need a valid max stack size if nothing else, no length encoded for code/constant/lineinfo sections (and I think need 0 length for locals and upvalue names even if not including). Constants seem messed up. What is 0x1b supposed to be? Need type encoding, length if string

Comment: Just compare with a bytecode file from the normal compiler...